# Inkscape does not support SVG <use> directive

Tags: inkscape, svg

I was trying to import an SVG file that I made using the SVG `<use>` directive:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/use

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 30 10" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle id="myCircle" cx="5" cy="5" r="4" stroke="blue" />
  <use href="#myCircle" x="10" fill="blue" />
  <use href="#myCircle" x="20" fill="white" stroke="red" />
</svg>
```

However, Inkscape seems not supporting it, I was wondering if there is any workaround so I can load the file using Inkscape. Or generally how can I convert SVG with use directive to fully explicit SVG file.

Comment: Please check [this answer to a previous question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/155424/165916). In short: Inkscape still requires the `xlink:` namespace for the `href` attribute. Please ignore the deprecation notice on the MDN page. It is still recommended to always use `xlink:href` instead of just `href`.

Comment: @Xrott thanks that solved the issue